# Rails Thin Servers no PID found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I'm running Rails on Ubuntu using Nginx web server and 5 Thin app servers.

Once a day the system gets very slow and sometimes hangs-up.

I'm not sure if it's the Thin servers, but when I stop the servers when it's hung, I get:

```
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid
```

Here is the log showing the Thin start and stop:

```
bitnami@linux:/opt/bitnami$ thin -C projects/myapp/current/config/thin.yml start
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ...
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3001 ...
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3002 ...
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3003 ...
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3004 ...


bitnami@linux:/opt/bitnami$ thin -C projects/myapp/current/config/thin.yml stop
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ...
Sending QUIT signal to process 21921 ...
>> Exiting!
Timeout!
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3001 ...
Sending QUIT signal to process 21945 ...
>> Exiting!
Timeout!
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3001.pid
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3002 ...
Sending QUIT signal to process 21969 ...
>> Exiting!
Timeout!
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3002.pid
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3003 ...
Sending QUIT signal to process 21993 ...
Timeout!
Sending KILL signal to process 21993 ...
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3004 ...
Sending QUIT signal to process 22017 ...
>> Exiting!
bitnami@linux:/opt/bitnami$
```

Sometimes it finds PIDS other times it doesn't.  What does this mean?

Thanks!

Comment: After starting the servers, have you looked in `tmp/pids` to see if the files are being created?  If so, do they contain the right process ids?

Comment: Yes, they get created at start-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had exactly the same annoying problem**

I've found that if the server crashes on startup, the pid file gets created but there is no pid in the file. Try cat'ing the log file for the server ./logs/thin.3001.log and look for errors. You could also try starting the server manually via

```
rails s -p 3000
```

and see if there are any errors thrown.

Good luck

Chris

Comment: Your instruction is very helpful. I tail the thin.log while starting thin and quickly find out the problem. Thanks!